# Angular Service Worker, Forcing update activation and lazy loading

Tags: angular, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I'm writing an Angular PWA (Angular Version 8.2), and I have some troubles with automatic updates on iOS. I therefore thought of triggering the service worker's checkForUpdate regularly (as described in [Checking for updates](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-communications#checking-for-updates)), and forcing the update activation as described in [Forcing update activation](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-communications#forcing-update-activation) if an update is available.
The [angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-communications#forcing-update-activation) states however, that forcing update activation might brake lazy-loading:

> Doing this could break lazy-loading into currently running apps, especially if the lazy-loaded chunks use filenames with hashes, which change every version.

Looking through angular's service worker implementation (and documentation), I can not figure out, why or in what scenario this could break lazy-loading.

I would appreciate if anyone could explain, why this would break lazy-loading.

Answer (score 0):

The module name is translated to the filename at compile-time, so if your Router is looking for `0.abcdef.js` but you've activated the update, chances are `0.abcdef.js` doesn't exist anymore and was replaced by `0.cbafed.js`.

This might not be the case, however, if the old file is kept.